# show that the recursive relation of a random walk is unique

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, random-walk

Let $x(s)$ be a recursive equation defined for integers $s$ on $0 ≤ s ≤ t$
$$x(s) = x(s + 1)a + x(s − 1)b \text{ if } 0 < s < t$$ 
and boundary conditions $x(0) = u$, $x(t) = v$

Let $0<a<1$ and $a+b = 1$, and $t$ be a positive integer.

Show $x(s)$ is unique.

I noticed that the solution to the recursive equation is of the form $x(s) = \alpha + \beta\rho^s ,\rho=\frac{b}{a}$

Found that $$\alpha = \frac{v-u\rho^t}{1-\rho^t}$$
$$\beta = \frac{u-v}{1-\rho^t}$$

So the solution is of the form 
$$
x(s) = \frac{v-u\rho^t}{1-\rho^t} +  \frac{u-v}{1-\rho^t}\rho^s
$$

Is this the right approach? I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Keyword: Maximum principle.

Comment: can you please explain?